# Calculate the continued fraction

Tags: continued-fractions

Find  the  limit

$$
\frac{\color{red}{1+\cfrac{3}{4+\cfrac{7}{8+\cfrac{11}{12+\dots}}}}}{\color{blue}{2+\cfrac{5}{6+\cfrac{9}{10+\cfrac{13}{14+\dots}}}}}.
$$
By direct calculation I have got that it is about 0.59*** but I hope there exists an exact expression.

EDIT1: $\color{red}{1},\color{blue}{2},\color{red}{3,4},\color{blue}{5,6},\color{red}{7,8},\color{blue}{9,10},\color{red}{11,12},\color{blue}{13,14},\ldots$

EDIT2: By some calculation I conjecture that

$$
\frac{\color{red}{1+\cfrac{3}{4+\cfrac{7}{8+\cfrac{11}{12+\dots}}}}}{\color{blue}{2+\cfrac{5}{6+\cfrac{9}{10+\cfrac{13}{14+\dots}}}}} \to \frac{\varphi}{e},
$$
where $\varphi$ is the golden ratio and $e$ is as usual  $2.71...$

Comment: Where is this problem from?

Comment: What are the values of the numerator and denominator?

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Just one of my students asks me today

Comment: @marty cohen  seems numerator is very close to golden ratio and denominator is close to $e$

Comment: Since $\phi$ is a quadratic irrational, its continued fraction is periodic, so it can't be the numerator. The denominator looks like one of Euler's continued fractions for $e$.

Comment: the denominator is greater then $e$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "exact expression" (as follows from [this result](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3283627)) uses the [confluent hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluent_hypergeometric_function): $$L=\frac{a_3}{3a_1}\left(1+\frac{3a_4}{5a_2}\right),\qquad a_n={}_1F_1\left(\frac{2n-1}{4};\frac{2n+1}{4};\frac14\right).$$ I don't think it can be simplified. Note that numerically $L\approx0.59518$... while $\varphi/e\approx0.59524$...