# Reference to the continued fractions of the form $\mathop{\text{K}}_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{an+b}{cn+d}$

Tags: reference-request, continued-fractions

With some heuristic computation, I conjecture that the generalized continued fraction (CGD)

$$ \mathop{\Large\text{K}}_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{an+b}{cn+d} = \dfrac{a+b}{(c+d)+\dfrac{2a+b}{(2c+d)+\dfrac{3a+b}{(3c+d)+\ldots}}} $$

written in Gasus' Kettenbruch notation, has the following form

$$ \mathop{\Large\text{K}}_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{an+b}{cn+d} = \frac{ \frac{a+b}{c} \beta {}_1F_{1}(\alpha, \beta; \gamma)}{\beta (\beta-1) {}_1F_{1}(\alpha, \beta; \gamma) + \alpha \gamma {}_1F_{1}(\alpha+1, \beta+1; \gamma) } $$

where $\alpha = \frac{a}{c^2} + \frac{d}{c} - \frac{b}{a} $, $\beta = \frac{a}{c^2} + \frac{d}{c} + 2$, and $\gamma = -\frac{a}{c^2}$, and ${}_1F_{1}$ is the [Kummer's confluent hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluent_hypergeometric_function).

Given the simplicity of the method I applied, I am fairly certain that this type of answer has already been known in literature, although I was unable to find it with a quick googling. So I would like to seek for a help for identifying references to this type of result. I am by no means an expert of this field, and was only mildly motivated by the project [*Ramanujan Machine*](http://www.ramanujanmachine.com/) which seeks to discover novel type of GCF identities experimentally.

In short, any help for identifying references would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An easier-to-read form is obtained if one starts at $n=0$ instead of $n=1$: $${\raise{-1ex}\mathop{\huge\text{K}}_{n=0}^{\infty}}\frac{an+b}{cn+d}=\frac{a}{c}\frac{{_1F_1}'(\alpha;\beta;\gamma)}{_1F_1(\alpha;\beta;\gamma)}=\frac{a}{c}\frac{\alpha}{\beta}\frac{_1F_1(\alpha+1;\beta+1;\gamma)}{_1F_1(\alpha;\beta;\gamma)},\\\alpha:=\frac{b}{a},\quad\beta:=\frac{a}{c^2}+\frac{d}{c},\quad\gamma:=\frac{a}{c^2}.\quad\color{LightGray}{\left[\frac{a}{c}\frac{\alpha}{\beta}=\cfrac{b}{d+\cfrac{a}{c}}\right]}$$ It can be deduced from [one of the recurrences](https://dlmf.nist.gov/13.3#E13) for $_1F_1$, and there are other approaches (I did it myself some time ago, via ODEs for exponential generating functions for the convergents of the CF, which transform into Kummer's ODE for $_1F_1$ after a linear change of variable). In fact the closely related form $$\frac{_1F_1(a+1;b+1;z)}{_1F_1(a;b;z)}=\frac{b}{b-z}{\vphantom{1}\atop+}\frac{a+1}{b+1-z}{\vphantom{1}\atop+}\frac{a+2}{b+2-z}{\vphantom{1}\atop{+\ldots}}$$ does appear in literature (say, in [Jones & Thron](https://zbmath.org/0603.30009) section $7.3.3$). It may well be known since Kummer, and certainly known to [Nørlund](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niels_Erik_N%C3%B8rlund) who found an $_2F_1$ analogue ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3757207) is the idea, the "ODE for EGF" way).

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer! As I am not well acquainted with ${}_1F_{1}$, I will take time to swallow what is described here. However, the idea of using recurrence relations already sounds very convincing to me.