# Closed expression for a given continued fraction

Tags: special-functions, continued-fractions

Does anyone know a closed-form expression for the continued fraction
$$F(x) = \cfrac{x}{x+\cfrac{x}{x+1+\cfrac{2x}{x+2+\cfrac{3x}{x+3+\cfrac{4x}{x+4+\cdots}}}}}?$$
According to page 181 of *An Invitation to Modern Number Theory*, by Miller and Takloo-Bighash, one has $F(1) = e-2$.  Numerical exploration suggests that $F(0^+) = F(0^-) = \frac{1}{2}$ and $F(\frac{1}{2}) = e^{1/2}-1$, and also $F(\infty) = 1$, and maybe also $$1-F(x) \sim \frac{1}{x} \ (x \to \infty).$$  Also, its domain of convergence on $\mathbb{R}$ appears to inlude $(-\frac{1}{2},\infty)$, but I'm not sure about the negative reals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Conclusion.** In this answer, we will provide a sketch of proof of the identity

\begin{align*}
F(x)
&= 1 - \int_{0}^{1} \frac{(1-\xi)^{2x}}{(1+\xi)^2} e^{x \xi} \, \mathrm{d}\xi \tag{$x > -\tfrac{1}{2}$}\\
&= x \int_{0}^{1} (1-\xi)^{2x-1} e^{x \xi} \, \mathrm{d}\xi. \tag{$x > 0$}
\end{align*}

Before delving into the proof, note that this allows us to find a closed-form for the values of $F(\cdot)$ at positive half-integer arguments. For example,

\begin{align*}
F(\tfrac{1}{2}) &= \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{2}e^{\xi/2} \, \mathrm{d}\xi = \sqrt{e} - 1, \\
F(1) &= \int_{0}^{1} (1-\xi) e^{\xi} \, \mathrm{d}\xi = e - 2, \\
F(2) &= \int_{0}^{1} 2 (1-\xi)^3 e^{2\xi} \, \mathrm{d}\xi = \frac{3e^2}{4}-\frac{19}{4}.
\end{align*}

The formula above also allows us to analyze the asymptotic behavior of $F(x)$ as $x\to\infty$. Indeed, substitute $\xi = s/x$ to write

$$ F(x) = 1 - \frac{1}{x} \int_{0}^{x} \frac{(1-s/x)^{2x}}{(1+s/x)^2} e^{s} \, \mathrm{d}s. $$

Then, as $x \to \infty$, the dominated convergence theorem yields

$$ \lim_{x\to\infty} \int_{0}^{x} \frac{(1-s/x)^{2x}}{(1+s/x)^2} e^{s} \, \mathrm{d}s
= \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-s} \, \mathrm{d}s = 1. $$

Therefore it follows that

$$ F(x) = 1 - \frac{1+o(1)}{x} \qquad\text{as}\qquad x \to \infty. $$

---

**Preliminary.** Let $(a_n)_{n\geq0}$ and $(b_n)_{n\geq 0}$ with $b_0 = 1$ be given, and define $(h_n)_{n\geq0}$ and $(k_n)_{n\geq0}$ by

$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
h_n &= a_n h_{n-1} + b_n h_{n-2}, & h_{-2} &= 0, & h_{-1} &= 1 \\
k_n &= a_n k_{n-1} + b_n k_{n-2}, & k_{-2} &= 1, & k_{-1} &= 0
\end{aligned}
\right.
\tag{1}
$$

Then it is well-known that

$$ \frac{h_n}{k_n}
= a_0 + \cfrac{b_1}{a_1 + \cfrac{b_2 }{a_2 + \dfrac{\ddots }{\ddots \cfrac{b_{n-1}}{a_{n-1} + \cfrac{b_n}{a_n} } }}} $$

**Analysis.** To make the notation neater, we will analyze $x/F(x)$ instead. Then by the observation above, we find that $F(x)$ can be defined by the relation

$$ \frac{x}{F(x)} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{h_n}{k_n}, \tag{2} $$

where $(h_n)$ and $(k_n)$ are defined by $\text{(1)}$ with the choices $ a_n = x + n $ and $ b_n = nx $.

From this point on, we will assume we know that the limit $\text{(2)}$ converges and then focus on the question of identifying its value. To this end, we consider the power series

$$ y(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{c_n}{n!} z^n, \qquad \text{where} \quad c_n = (n+x)c_{n-1} + nxc_{n-2}. \tag{3} $$

**1.** By noting that

\begin{align*}
\frac{c_n}{n!}
&= \left(1 + \frac{x}{n}\right) \frac{c_{n-1}}{(n-1)!} + \frac{x}{n-1} \frac{c_{n-2}}{(n-2)!},
\end{align*}

it follows that the sequence $M_{n} = \max_{0\leq j \leq n} |c_j/j!|$ satisfies

$$ M_{n} \leq \left(1 + \frac{|x|}{n} + \frac{|x|}{n-1} \right) M_{n-1}. $$

This allows to deduce that $M_{n} = \mathcal{O}(n^{2|x|})$, and in particular, the radius of convergence of $\text{(3)}$ is at least $1$.

**2.** Plugging the recurrence relation for $(c_n)$ to $\text{(3)}$,

\begin{align*}
y(z)
&= c_0 + c_1 z + \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{c_n}{n!} z^n \\
&= c_0 + c_1 z + \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{(n+x)c_{n-1} + nxc_{n-2}}{n!} z^n \\
&= c_0 + c_1 z + x \Biggl( \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{c_n}{(n+1)!} z^{n+1} - c_0 z \Biggr) + z ( y(z) - c_0 ) + xz \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{c_n}{(n+1)!} z^{n+1}.
\end{align*}

Solving this for the sum $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{c_n}{(n+1)!} z^{n+1}$, we get

$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{c_n}{(n+1)!} z^{n+1}
= \frac{(1-z)y(z) + c_0 ((x+1)z - 1) - c_1 z}{x(z+1)}. $$

Taking the differential operator $x(z+1)^2\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}z}$ to both sides and rearranging, we end up with the linear ODE of the form

$$ y'(z) + \frac{x(z+1)^2 + 2}{z^2-1} y(z) = \frac{(2+x) c_0 - c_1}{z^2 - 1}. $$

This can be solved using the integrating factor method:

$$ y(z) = \frac{1}{\mu(z)} \left( \int_{0}^{z} \frac{(2+x) c_0 - c_1}{\xi^2 - 1} \mu(\xi) \, \mathrm{d}\xi + c_0\mu(0) \right), \tag{4} $$

where $\mu(z)$ is the integrating factor given by

$$ \mu(z) = \exp\left( \int \frac{x(z+1)^2 + 2}{z^2-1} \, \mathrm{d}z \right) = \frac{e^{x(z+1)}}{z+1} (1-z)^{2x+1}. $$

**3.** Now we define $y_h(z)$ and $y_k(z)$ by

$$ y_h(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{h_n}{n!} z^n \qquad\text{and}\qquad y_k(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{k_n}{n!} z^n. $$

Then by noting that

$$
\begin{cases} h_0 = x, \\ h_1 = x(x+2), \end{cases} \qquad
\begin{cases} k_0 = 1, \\ k_1 = x+1, \end{cases}
$$

it follows from $\text{(4)}$ that

$$ y_h(z) = \frac{x\mu(0)}{\mu(z)} = \frac{x (z+1)e^{-x z}}{(1-z)^{2x+1}}
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
y_k(z) = \frac{1}{\mu(z)} \left( \int_{0}^{z} \frac{1}{\xi^2 - 1} \mu(\xi) \, \mathrm{d}\xi + \mu(0) \right). $$

In particular, $y_k(z)$ diverges to $-\infty$ as $z \to 1^-$ for $x > -\frac{1}{2}$. So, assuming $x > -\frac{1}{2}$, we may invoke the following 'regularization trick':

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{h_n}{k_n} = \lim_{z \to 1^-} \frac{y_h(z)}{y_k(z)}. $$

From this, it follows that

$$ \frac{x}{F(x)}
= \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{h_n}{k_n}
= \frac{x\mu(0)}{\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{\xi^2 - 1} \mu(\xi) \, \mathrm{d}\xi + \mu(0)} $$

and therefore

\begin{align*}
F(x)
= 1 + \frac{1}{\mu(0)} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{\xi^2 - 1} \mu(\xi) \, \mathrm{d}\xi
= 1 - \int_{0}^{1} \frac{(1-\xi)^{2x}}{(1+\xi)^2} e^{x \xi} \, \mathrm{d}\xi.
\end{align*}

When $x > 0$, we can perform integration by parts to get

$$ F(x) = x \int_{0}^{1} (1-\xi)^{2x-1} e^{x \xi} \, \mathrm{d}\xi. $$

Comment: Wow, this is genius!  How did you do this?  Do you have a closed expression for its value at half positive integer arguments?

Comment: @JesseElliott Glad it helped :) As for the positive half-integer arguments, you may try to find a recurrence relation for the sequence $$I_k = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{(1-t)^k}{k!} e^{-st} \, \mathrm{d}t $$ for any given $s$ (Hint: perform integration by parts!) and then use that to find the general formula for $I_k$. This will allow you to identify those special values of $F$.

Comment: Mathematica says the integral is $e^x x^{-2 x+1} (\Gamma(2 x) - \Gamma(2 x, x))$ for $x > 0$.

Comment: @JesseElliott, It is indeed related to incomplete gamma function. (To see this, you may substitute $\xi=1-t/x$ in the integral representation of $F$.) But I am not sure if that is particularly informative when you are hunting for some closed-form special values of $F$.

Comment: Or, equivalently, $e^x x^{-2x+1} \gamma(2x,x)$.  It is nice because I am quite familiar with the lower incomplete gamma function $\gamma(s,z)$, whereas the integral is complicated.  I wonder, is the expression valued for $x$ complex with real part $> 0$?

Comment: @JesseElliott, Indeed, all my computations are valid provided $\operatorname{Re}(x)>-\frac{1}{2}$ and the corresponding convergents, $h_n/k_n$, converge. I have little doubt that the convergents will converge for $x \geq 0$, but honestly I haven't seriously thought about this for other values of $x$.

Comment: I bet it works on much more of the domain of $\gamma(s, z)$!  Might there be a reference for this, or can you generalize the argument?

Comment: Ah, maybe it is implied by 
$$\gamma(s, z) = \cfrac{z^s e^{-z}}{s - \cfrac{s z}{s+1 + \cfrac{z}{s+2 - \cfrac{(s+1)z}
{s+3 + \cfrac{2z}{s+4 - \cfrac{(s+2)z}{s+5 + \cfrac{3z}{s+6 - \ddots}}}}}}},$$ which, according to Wikipedia, is valid for $s$ not a negative integer.

Comment: @JesseElliott I also suspect that $-\frac{1}{2}$ is rather the limitation of my approach. Unfortunately, I am not an expertise of this topic as I have never formally exposed to it. Maybe you might be able to find some references in [this posting](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3283627/9340).

Comment: I found it!  It is equation (12.6.30) in Handbook of Continued Fractions for Special Functions.  It is valid for all complex $x$ except for the nonpositive half-integers.

Comment: @JesseElliott See also http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.9.E1 with $\gamma^*$ being http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.2.E6 In general, the DLMF is highly recommended if you are dealing with special functions.

Comment: True, I know that, but when you have a given continued fraction, it's not easy to use sources to find what it's equal to.  Rather it's the other way around: if you know the special function, then it's easy to hunt down what its continued fraction expansions are.